# Function not working on Firefox but is on Chrome

Tags: jquery, function, firefox, event-listener

I believe it has something to do with the event listener, but this function works totally fine on Chrome
([it's the "Show More" button on this page](http://thepostrider.com/2020-vice-presidential-tracker/#)) but doesn't work on Firefox to show the rest of the table rows.

```
jQuery('#vpranktable').find('tr:gt(10)').hide();

jQuery(".viewVPranktable").on("click", function(event) {
  jQuery('#vpranktable').find('tr:gt(10)').toggle();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: There's nothing in this code snippet that shouldn't work in any browser.

Comment: Your web page doesn't work for me in Chrome. Clicking on Show More just changes it to Show Less, but doesn't show the rest.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal snippet inside your question (using the toolbar), that has a table, a link, a click handler, .... that reproduces the issue (in Firefox)?

Comment: You need to put the event bindings inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Because you're loading `VP-tracker.js` before the body is loaded.

Comment: Oof okay -- I was fairly new to JavaScript when I built this out as you can tell and recently just transferred it over to a new format on the site so I'm sure I broke something. There's several different events all running on the one page -- think I could just drop the entire VP-tracker.js into it's own event?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `myClick()` function two times. In the onload of the table as well as the image on the first row. Your function is called twice. Remove one of them and it should work

Comment: Ooh good catch -- though it doesn't appear that resolved the issue on Firefox when I removed the first myClick() function.

Comment: It should. In my Firefox its running the function twice so removing one should work. Can you verify that the function is being called on your side and if so how many times?

Comment: It should only be in there once now -- I only see it on the load for the first row -- but still not getting anything else on the "Show More" / "Show Less" other than changing the text. I'm fairly new to Javascript as you can tell...